# Python 3 with CSV reader and StringIO using excessive memory

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, stringio

The CSV file here is about 500MB with 2.7 million rows. Through extensive testing, I have verified that `for row in read_new:` quadruples memory consumption, and I can't understand why. The memory increase does not happen before or after the `for` statement.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?

I understand there are better ways to execute this script, but I have my reasons for doing it this way. I'm just trying to figure out why this is happening and if there is perhaps a more appropriate buffer to use than StringIO() for this purpose.

```
import io
import csv
import time

filename = 'rcs_batch_032519.csv'

csv_fob = open(filename, 'r')
fix_fob = io.StringIO()

reader = csv.reader(csv_fob)
writer = csv.writer(fix_fob)

for row in reader:
    writer.writerow(row)

fix_fob.seek(0)
read_new = csv.reader(fix_fob)

# Memory explodes here, from 634MB to 2.36GB, after executing 'for' statement
for row in read_new:
    time.sleep(30)
    pass
```

Comment: If you're going to read the entire file into memory, why don't you read it into a list of lists instead so that the data is better structured and more efficient since you don't have to rely on another instance of `csv.reader` to parse the CSV content again?

Comment: @blhsing I will probably end up doing that at this point, but I'm also really curious about this observed behavior.

Comment: @OnNIX: At this point *"executing 'for' statement"* you have your data **3-Times** in memory. Compute 634MB * 3 + overhead